# If A, B are n by n matrices, and x is a vector, does (Ax)(Bx) = (AB)x?

Tags: linear-algebra

It says it all in the title. Just a simple question about multiplication of matrices/vectors. I saw this in an old youtube video and in one of the steps, they multiplied the following two equations together:

Ax=cx

Bx=dx

Where c and d are scalars, to obtain

(Ax)(Bx) = (cx)(dx)

And then they simplified it to (AB)x=(cd)x

I didn't think you could even multiply the equations together since the dimensions don't match (Ax and Bx are both n by 1 matrices), and on top of that shouldn't you get (x)^2? Or am I missing something here and it's just a property of matrix/vector distribution?

Comment: I agree, it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The context makes that unlikely, and the conclusion fails if that's what's intended.

Comment: $(cx)(dx)$ only makes sense if $x$ is a $1\times 1$ vector; that is, if $A$ and $B$ are row vectors/matrices. I.e., if they are $1\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the expression
$$
A(x)B(x)
$$
is nonsense.

But this is true:
$$
(AB)(x) = A(B(x)) = A(dx) = cdx.
$$

It's probably what was intended.